# display child pages in wordpress sidebar only on certain page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one page template for all pages of my WP site. Each of these pages have their sub-pages, and I am trying to find a way to somehow put a code in my page.php template that would show in the sidebar only links of the sub-pages of the page i am currently on.

I used this code:

```
<?php 

$parent = 9;
$args=array(
'child_of' => $parent
);
$pages = get_pages($args);  
if ($pages) {
$pageids = array();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
$pageids[]= $page->ID;
 }

$args=array(
'title_li' => 'Tree of Parent Page ' . $parent,
'include' =>  $parent . ',' . implode(",", $pageids)
 );
 wp_list_pages($args);
 }
 ?>
```

And it worked but it is showing subpages of the page "9" on all of my pages. I guess that I have to set some conditions, such as "if page_is()" but I don't really know how to do that, so if someone is willing to help I would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$post->ID` to retrieve the id of the current page dynamically:

```
wp_list_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
```

Comment: Sorry for this dumb question, but where in my code should i actually put this?

Comment: @Astronaut: wherever you want the list of links to appear.  If you have a sidebar.php and want the links to appear in the sidebar, put it there.

Comment: No, I mean, this part of my code you wrote, where to put it in  the code I wrote here :)

Comment: @astronaut I think you could just replace the code you wrote in your post entirely and substitute the line in my answer (adding your `title_li` as an argument in my `wp_list_pages()`).

Answer (score 0):

Do it with CSS..

You can hide .children, and show .current_page_item .children with the twenty twelve theme. It still technically outputs the tags, but the CSS hides it well.

Example: http://dev.napkinworks.ca/boardoftrade/